# Gulp environment variable in a file?

Tags: gulp

I need to alter my Gulp task depending on if the environment is development or production. Ive found lots of tutorials on this but I need to set this variable from an actual file, not a command. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file can be a json, you can just..

```
var file = require('custom.json');

if (file.option) {
...
}
```